# grep words around a token

Tags: grep

I have some lines in a file like:

```
This is one word1:word2 of the lines    
This is another word3:word4 of the lines    
Line without a match    
Yet another line word5:word6 for test
```

I need to grep for `:` and to return words just before and after `:`.

Output I need from greping above lines is

```
word1:word2
word3:word4
word5:word6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU `grep`:

```
start cmd:> echo "This is one word1:word2 of the lines" |
  grep -Eo '[[:alnum:]]+:[[:alnum:]]+'
word1:word2

start cmd:> echo "This is one wordx:wordy of the lines" |
  grep -Eo '[[:alpha:]]*:[[:alpha:]]*'
wordx:wordy

start cmd:> echo "This is one wo_rdx:wo_rdy of the lines" |
  grep -Eo '[[:alpha:]_]*:[[:alpha:]_]*'
wo_rdx:wo_rdy
```

Comment: This works great for alpha numeric words. Please advice the case of underscores also. I mean the words can be like word_one_alpha word_two_beta etc. Thanks a lot for the quick help.

Answer (score 1):

For all case of your desired result, you can use GNU `grep` with PCRE support(`-P`) and its word regex (`\w`) as following:

```
grep -oP '\w+:\w+' file
```

Input file:

```
This is one word1:word2 of the lines and another is word:word   
This is another word3:word4 of the lines  and this is not wordnot::wordnot
Line without a match    
Yet another line word5:word6 for test
This is one wo_rdx:wo_rdy of the lines
This is one wordx:wordy of the lines
```

Output:

```
word1:word2
word:word
word3:word4
word5:word6
wo_rdx:wo_rdy
wordx:wordy
```

As you can see `grep` doesn't match `wordnot::wordnot` pattern, because it has a extra `:` between itself.

Comment: you don't need to go for character class. Just `grep -oP '\w+:\w+' file` would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

POSIXly (though beware some `tr` implementations (like GNU's) don't work properly with multi-byte characters).

```
tr -s '[:space:]_' '[\n*]' << 'EOF' |
  grep -xE '[[:alnum:]_]+:[[:alnum:]_]+'
This is one word1:word2 of the lines and another is word:word   
This is another word3:word4 of the lines  and this is not wordnot::wordnot
Line without a match    
Yet another line word5:word6 for test
This is one wo_rdx:wo_rdy of the lines
This is one wordx:wordy of the lines
not/a:match
EOF
```

Gives:

```
word1:word2
word:word
word3:word4
word5:word6
rdx:wo
wordx:wordy
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were to use `sed` to do this thing, it might be done like:

```
sed -n 's/\( *: *\)*\([^ ]*:[^ ]* *\)*.\{,1\}/\2/g;/./p' <<\IN 
This is one word1:word2 of the lines
This is another word3:word4 of the lines
Line without :a :match
Yet another line word5:word6 for test:123:test
IN
```

#### OUTPUT

```
word1:word2 
word3:word4 
word5:word6 test:123:test
```

Answer (score 0):

Through grep,

```
grep -oP '[^:\s]+:[^:\s]+' file
```

OR

```
grep -oP '\S+?:\S+' file
```

The above command not only fetches the strings like `foo:bar` but also `?foo:bar?`